# Bits and Bytes of Computer Science

Tags: bit

How many different values can be stored in 1 bit? Wouldn't it be a 1 and 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store two values, either a 0 or a 1.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The bit represents the state of an electrical current which only has two values - on and off.

Answer (score 1):

A bit is a contraction of binary digit.it only store 0 or 1 in computer science.
1 byte=8 bits
1KB=1024Byte=8*1024bit
1MB=1024KB
1GB=1024MB
1TB=1024GB

Comment: Note, the definition of "kilobyte", "megabyte", etc is semi controversial. Some people (mostly memory/CPU manufacturers and many programmers) define them as powers of 1024 (2^10; because they work with powers of 2 all the time), and others (mostly hard drive/network device makers and people who rightly assume the names are based on the metric system) define them as powers of 1000. It's been suggested that "kibibyte", "mebibyte", etc be used for powers of 1024, but frankly, those just sound stupid. (The abbreviations aren't that bad, though; just stick an 'i' between the K/M/G/T/etc and the B.)